# Is there a way to prevent duplicate coroutine calls?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I'm fairly new to Kotlin coroutines - but is there a way to tag them and make sure only one of them is running at any given time?

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    print("Hello World", timestamp)
}

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    print("Hello World", timestamp)
}

// "Hello World" 1000
// "Hello World" 1000
```

I was hoping for a solution that resembles something like this

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO, "tag_a") {
    print("Hello World", timestamp)
}

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO, "tag_a") {
    print("Hello World", timestamp)
}

// "Hello World" 1000
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on why would you want to do this?

Comment: To easily prevent duplicate network IO calls when one is already running.

Comment: Instead of tagging coroutines, most likely you should be able to structure your code in a way which prevents duplicate network calls. If want to tag them anyways, you can use normal Kotlin booleans and set them to true inside coroutine. Before setting check if it is already true. If it is, just return.

Comment: Although I appreciate the response, I'll stick with the question as is for now to see if anyone else has a different proposed solution.

Comment: I'd instead take Arpit's suggestion, as you're not only trying to fight the framework, but also creating issues for the future you. Do the things the way the are designed to be done, not the way it's convenient because of past decisions (or decisions made without having the full picture). We all make mistakes when making architecture decisions, the sooner you fix them, the merrier you will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to create a nullable variable of type `Job` and assign a lauсhed job to it:

```
private var job: Job? = null

job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO, "tag_a") {
    print("Hello World", timestamp)
}
```

When trying to launch another coroutine just check whether this job is finished. So the whole code would look like the following:

```
private var job: Job? = null

@Synchronized
fun doSomething() {
    val currentJob = job
    // launch if job is null or completed
    if (currentJob == null || currentJob.isCompleted) {
        job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //print("Hello World", timestamp)
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, usage of `GlobalScope` is discouraged, consider creating your own scope.

Comment: Is it safe to read and write variables from outside a coroutine scope? Since they might be in entirely different threads?

Comment: In that case need to somehow to synchronize the call to `doSomething()`, for example by adding `@Synchronized` annotation.

Comment: @Sergio will the next job wait for the previous `job`? Like when you call `job.join()` or `job.cancelAndJoin()`?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan no, it will not wait for the previous job to finish. It just checks whether the job is launched, and if not launches it.

Comment: @Sergio, could you please update the if statement to the following so your code actually compiles for future readers? `if (currentJob == null || (currentJob?.isCompleted == true))`

Comment: There is no need to use nullable check,  `currentJob` is smart casted to a non null variable.

Answer (score 2):

I keep a reference to the job outside of my coroutine and call `job?.join()`. Sample:

```
private var job: Job? = null
coroutineScope.launch {
        job?.join()
        job = coroutineContext.job
}
```

Tags are way cleaner in my opninion.

Comment: This is a great idea. My only concern being possible issues with passing data around. Is it safe to read and write from `job: Job?` since it is a variable that is in another thread?

Comment: In my use cases, I didn't see any issues with this. My use cades were relatively simple, so I can't tell without experimentation.